# Error trying to show data from db on table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was working this side project trying to learn CI, but currently got some errors that i haven't found the answer to. I already tried some suggestions/answer like `die($this->db->last_query());` and `var_dump`
but it still shown the error. 
The data is shown on my view using `<?php echo print($list_rawmat) ?>`
but it wont show up in the table (same page)
Here's the view

```html
<?php echo print($list_rawmat) ?>
<div id="list_data_rawmat">
  <table class="table table-hover text-centered">
    <tr>
      <td><b>No.</td>
            <td><b>Jenis Barang</td>
            <td><b>Nama Barang</td>
            <td><b>Harga Satuan</td>
            <td><b>Jumlah</td>
            <td><b>Satuan</td>
            <td><b>Berat</td>
            <td><b>Edit/Delete</td>
        </tr>
        <?php

        $i = 1;
             foreach($list_rawmat as $row)
            {
                $type = "Raw Material";
                echo "<tr> 
                <td>".$i++."</td>
                <td>".$type."</td>
                <td>".$row->rawmat_name."</td>
                <td>".$row->rawmat_price."</td>
                <td>".$row->qty."</td>
                <td>".$row->qty_nama."</td>
                <td>".$row->weight."</td>
    </tr>"; 
            }
            ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's the model

```php
    *$proyek = AM1 (it was sent by previous page)
function list_rawmat($proyek){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_table g, order_detail b 
            WHERE g.project_id = '".$proyek."' AND g.order_detail_id = b.order_detail_id";
    $item_id = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    $i = 0;
    $result = array();
    foreach($item_id as $row){
        if ($row->rawmat_id != null) {
            $sql2 = "SELECT g.order_id, g.order_date, g.total, b.qty, i.rawmat_id, i.rawmat_name, i.rawmat_price, b.weight, h.qty_nama
        FROM order_table g, order_detail b, raw_material i, quantity_type h
        WHERE g.project_id = '".$proyek."' AND b.rawmat_id = i.rawmat_id 
        AND h.qty_type_id = b.qty_type_id AND g.order_detail_id = b.order_detail_id ";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql2);
            $result[$i++] = $query->result();
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and lastly here's the controller

```php
*$this->session->project_id = AM1 (sent from view before the view in question)
function view_data_rawmat(){
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/c_data/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->m_data->count();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['next_link'] = 'Selanjutnya';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Sebelumnya';
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $offset=$this->uri->segment(3);     
    $data['list_rawmat'] = $this->m_data->list_rawmat($this->session->project_id);
    $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );
    $this->load->view ('view_header');
    $this->load->view ('view_data_rawmat',$data);
    $this->load->view ('view_footer');
    //die($this->db->last_query());
}
```

This is the result from `echo print_r ($list_rawmat);`

```php
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [order_id] => 5 [order_date] => 2016-04-05 [total] => 876348553 [qty] => 313 [rawmat_id] => 1 [rawmat_name] => WF - 346x174x6x9 L.9000mm [rawmat_price] => 7514 [weight] => 116624 [qty_nama] => Bh ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [order_id] => 6 [order_date] => 2016-11-10 [total] => 2147483647 [qty] => 10 [rawmat_id] => 2 [rawmat_name] => WF - 336x174x6x9 L.9000mm [rawmat_price] => 1848000 [weight] => 116624 [qty_nama] => Sets ) ) 
[1] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [order_id] => 5 [order_date] => 2016-04-05 [total] => 876348553 [qty] => 313 [rawmat_id] => 1 [rawmat_name] => WF - 346x174x6x9 L.9000mm [rawmat_price] => 7514 [weight] => 116624 [qty_nama] => Bh ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [order_id] => 6 [order_date] => 2016-11-10 [total] => 2147483647 [qty] => 10 [rawmat_id] => 2 [rawmat_name] => WF - 336x174x6x9 L.9000mm [rawmat_price] => 1848000 [weight] => 116624 [qty_nama] => Sets ) ) ) 1
```

I don't know why the array is like that, please enlighten me about this too.

Comment: Try echo '<pre>;print_r($list_rawmat);exit; this wil print array good, then edit question with that array @Vinzzy

Comment: @parthmahida sorry for asking but is your command any different than my already stated command `echo print_r ($list_rawmat);` ?

Comment: echo '<pre>' tag, will print array in readable format, if you have tried it without asking you did have the answer@Vinzzy

Comment: @ParthMahida so that means i already done it, so the data was sent onto my views but the table cant show it, i wonder what is wrong with it